# How to do $or and "and" in mongo query for java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I want to do both `AND` and `$or` operations in a single mongo query.

In mongo doc i have read mongo queries use `AND` by default.

If i use only or `$or`, its working. But if i try to use `AND` and `$or` its not working.

I have tried it like this

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("name", "Anbu");

BasicDBObject orQuery = new BasicDBObject();
orQuery.put("name", "Kalaio");
List<BasicDBObject> orQueries = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
orQueries.add(orQuery);

orQuery = new BasicDBObject();

orQuery.put("name", "Kumar");
orQueries.add(orQuery);

orQuery = new BasicDBObject();
orQuery.put("$or", orQueries);

query.put("$or", orQueries);

DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);//Not Working

DBCursor cur = coll.find(orQuery);//Working
```

Where i am doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Java driver, but it seems like you're trying to nest an "or". Unfortunately, that's not currently allowed in mongo. It's something planned in the future though. See these bugs for more info:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2585

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1089